# Generate missing rows using JOIN / CROSS JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, common-table-expression

I have 3 tables which are used to fill dynamic from value.

The table is represented by schema below.

[image]

User can add as many rows as possible, and the rows are shown to end user by template from FormField table.

The data that is saved in FormValues are only for not null values and any values that missing are not saved.

Now the problem is I have to generate report as expected below.

[image]

I have tried various combination of join / cross join, but none of them works as expected.

I am able to achieve this in C# via loops, but not able to do the same via SQL Server.

Script attached for DB

```
USE [SampleDb]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FormTemplate](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FormTemplate] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FormField](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FormId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FieldName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [FieldType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FormField] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[FormTemplate]    Script Date: 3/2/2020 10:10:22 PM ******/

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[FormValue]    Script Date: 3/2/2020 10:10:22 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FormValue](
    [FormId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FieldId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RowIndex] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FormValue] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FormValue] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FormId] ASC,
    [FieldId] ASC,
    [RowIndex] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[FormField] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FormField] ([Id], [FormId], [FieldName], [FieldType]) VALUES (1, 1, N'FirstName', N'string')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FormField] ([Id], [FormId], [FieldName], [FieldType]) VALUES (2, 1, N'LastName', N'string')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FormField] ([Id], [FormId], [FieldName], [FieldType]) VALUES (3, 1, N'Place', N'string')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FormField] ([Id], [FormId], [FieldName], [FieldType]) VALUES (4, 1, N'age', N'int')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FormField] ([Id], [FormId], [FieldName], [FieldType]) VALUES (5, 1, N'dob', N'date')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[FormField] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[FormTemplate] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FormTemplate] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (1, N'Sample')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[FormTemplate] OFF
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FormValue] ([FormId], [FieldId], [RowIndex], [FormValue]) VALUES (1, 1, 1, N'fname1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FormValue] ([FormId], [FieldId], [RowIndex], [FormValue]) VALUES (1, 2, 1, N'lname1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FormValue] ([FormId], [FieldId], [RowIndex], [FormValue]) VALUES (1, 2, 3, N'lname3')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FormValue] ([FormId], [FieldId], [RowIndex], [FormValue]) VALUES (1, 4, 5, N'20')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FormValue] ([FormId], [FieldId], [RowIndex], [FormValue]) VALUES (1, 5, 3, N'10/10/2020')
GO
```

Comment: *"I have tried various combination of join / cross join, but none of them works as expected."* Show us those attempts. A `CROSS JOIN` seems to be exactly what you want here. Also, please don't post sample data as images; someone with 18K reputation should now that we can't use that. DDL and DML statements are far more preferred, or at worst, tabular formatted `text`.

Comment: @Larnu - will attach script.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. PS Table initialization code formatted as heading plus rows makes an image unnecessary.

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. To describe a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution & a user knows how to use it. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. Please in code questions give a [mre]. Show what you have tried. Please don't ask us to write your code.

Comment: When you get a result that you don't expect/understand, stop trying to find your overall goal & find your misunderstanding.--Isolate the first unexpected/misunderstood subexpression & its input & output & learn what misconception, typo, wrong reasoning, etc led to it. (Debugging fundamental.) Ask about that. It seems like when clear this will be a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. [ask]

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question -- and then some.  But I don't update answers to conform to evolving questions.

You seem to want cross joins on three "tables".  The third needs to generate the `rowindex` values:

```
select f.id as formtemplateid, ff.id as formfieldid, v.rowindex,
       fv.value
from formtemplate f cross join
     formfield ff cross join
     (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) v(rowindex) left join
     formvalues fv
     on fv.formtemplateid = f.id and
        fv.formfieldid = ff.id and
        fv.rowindex = v.rowindex
order by f.id, ff.id, v.rowindex;
```

EDIT:

You can generate up to 100 numbers using a recursive CTE by doing:

```
with n as (
      select 1 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from n
      where n < 10  -- "10" is however many you want
     )
select n.n
from n;
```

Comment: This looks great, is there any way `values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)` can be achieved dynamically, as there can by any no of rows

Comment: @ParimalRaj . . . (1) That would be a different question.  (2) You can use a recursive CTE or numbers table.

Comment: Any hints on CTE ?, even rough idea would be fine, I will try and see where i end up .

Comment: Let me give it a try! Thanks for such quick help.

Comment: It seems like it cannot be done in one single query unless the cross join on rowindex cannot be dynamic which does not seems possible,

Comment: @ParimalRaj . . . I don't know what YOU mean by "dynamic".  Perhaps you should ask another question with a clear explanation and sample data and desired results.

Comment: Any idea on how to handle rowIndex in changed question?